# Please enable Arabic tags for Arabic.SE

Tags: feature-request

Can there be Arabic tags enabled for our site [Arabic.SE](https://arabic.stackexchange.com)?

So we can add them to questions, currently I try to add Arabic tags to my question but they disappear.

Comment: I can't migrate this to a site that's still in private beta. Please ask this on [its own meta site](http://meta.arabic.stackexchange.com) and see if there's community support for this request. Thanks!

Comment: @AnnaLear http://meta.arabic.stackexchange.com/questions/17/can-arabic-tagging-be-supported-provided